# editing table values code doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named aircondition (fields: ACName, Space, BTU, EnergyClass )and I want to edit these field.I use the following code to choose which aircondition to edit:

test1.php

```
<?php

    $username = "george";
    $password = "george123";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("my_db", $dbhandle);




                $table = "aircondition";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM aircondition";
                $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbhandle);
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo $row['ACName']. "<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[ACName]'>     Edit<br>
</a><br>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i have this one to update a certain field (BTU for example.)

edit.php

```
<?php
$username = "george";
$password = "george123";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db("my_db", $dbhandle);


$id = intval($_GET['edit']);
if($id > 0) {
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircondition WHERE ACNumber = '$id'");
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $newbtu = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newbtu']);

        $sql = "UPDATE aircondition SET BTU='$newbtu' WHERE ACNumber='$id'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Updating".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=edit.php?edit=$id'>";
    }


?>


<form action="edit.php?edit=<?= $id; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="newbtu" placeholer="test" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However,this one doesn't seem to work. Although i get no errors, nothing gets updated in the fields.

Comment: You are fetching from ACName and updating for ACNumber. Are you sure those 2 fields have same values?

Comment: Mysql functions are depreciated as of php 5.5, please use mysqli functions.

Comment: thank you, my bad .I am gonna be more careful next time to avoid mistakes like this one.

Comment: Side note: **Please don't use the mysql_ library** It is deprecated currently, and removed in newer versions of PHP. Please consider switching to [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @ohgodwhy copy cat ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are fetching the details from `ACName` and doing updation on `ACNumber` as @yajakass states in the comment.

Fixing it would solve the problem.

## Please don't use the mysql_ functions.Its use is depreciated.